# Change all the colours of text in rows in a column depending on the column name (datagrid)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to change all the colours of text in rows in a column depending on the column name in C#. How would I accomplish this?

So far I've tried the following:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DatePaid")
            {
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
```

The program builds - but it doesn't work at all

Comment: Unable to comment on my answer from.mobile. You have to put that code within form load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change particular colum forecolor then use this,

```
dataGridView1.Columns["DatePaid"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch`:

```
        switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
        {
            case "DatePaid":
                dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            case "Something":
                dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }
```